# How to sort the array of child items for the column "product_in_stock". Virtuemart 3

Tags: mysql, arrays, sorting

I have an array of child items in the parent. Below is the code by which it is formed. What you need to add or change the sorting array by product_in_stock? (First child items in stock)

Thanks!

```
function getProductChilds ($product_id) {
    if (empty($product_id)) {
        return array();
    }
    $db = JFactory::getDBO ();
    $db->setQuery (
       'SELECT * FROM `#__virtuemart_products` p
        LEFT JOIN `#__virtuemart_products_'.VMLANG.'` pl USING (`virtuemart_product_id`)
        LEFT JOIN `#__virtuemart_product_medias` pm USING (`virtuemart_product_id`)
        LEFT JOIN `#__virtuemart_medias` med USING (`virtuemart_media_id`)
        LEFT JOIN `#__virtuemart_product_prices` pp USING (`virtuemart_product_id`)
        WHERE `p`.`product_parent_id` = '. (int)$product_id . '
        GROUP BY `pm`.`virtuemart_product_id`'
    );
    return $db->loadObjectList ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agreed

```html
function getProductChilds ($product_id) {
if (empty($product_id)) {
return array();
}
$db = JFactory::getDBO ();
$db->setQuery ('SELECT * FROM `#__virtuemart_products` p
LEFT JOIN `#__virtuemart_products_'.VMLANG.'` pl USING (`virtuemart_product_id`)
LEFT JOIN `#__virtuemart_product_medias` pm USING (`virtuemart_product_id`)
LEFT JOIN `#__virtuemart_medias` med USING (`virtuemart_media_id`)
LEFT JOIN `#__virtuemart_product_prices` pp USING (`virtuemart_product_id`)
WHERE `p`.`product_parent_id` = '. (int)$product_id . '
GROUP BY `pm`.`virtuemart_product_id` ORDER BY p.`product_in_stock` DESC, `virtuemart_product_id` ASC');
return $db->loadObjectList ();
}
```

or

```html
function getProductChilds ($product_id) {
if (empty($product_id)) {
return array();
}
$db = JFactory::getDBO ();
$db->setQuery ('SELECT * FROM `#__virtuemart_products` p
LEFT JOIN `#__virtuemart_products_'.VMLANG.'` pl USING (`virtuemart_product_id`)
LEFT JOIN `#__virtuemart_product_medias` pm USING (`virtuemart_product_id`)
LEFT JOIN `#__virtuemart_medias` med USING (`virtuemart_media_id`)
LEFT JOIN `#__virtuemart_product_prices` pp USING (`virtuemart_product_id`)
WHERE `p`.`product_parent_id` = '. (int)$product_id . '
GROUP BY `pm`.`virtuemart_product_id` ORDER BY product_in_stock DESC');
return $db->loadObjectList ();
}
```